# How to secure DataBase settings from other users that have shell access to the server

Tags: security, mediawiki

I installed mediawiki on a webserver to some folder

```
drwxr-xr-x /server/web/mediawiki
```

This directory contains a file LocalSettings.php. Initially this file contained DataBase settings (user/password) as plain text.

Following the guide

```
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Securing_database_passwords
```

***1*** I tried to read protect LocalSettings.php with chmod

```
-rwx------ LocalSettings.php
```

and got an error when tried to reload mediawiki page in web-browser

```
failed to open stream: Permission denied in .../includes/WebStart.php
```

So I had to give reading access to LocalSettings.php to proceed

```
    -rwx---r-- LocalSettings.php
```

So, easy way didn't work for me for some reason.

**Question 1**: if you know why easy way didn't work, please, explain me.

***2*** Than I followed the other way described in the guide. I cut all the DataBase settings (user/password) from the LocalSettings.php to an external file (DBpsw.php) that I placed outside of the web accessible folder:

```
    drwxr-xr-x /home/mediawikiDBpsw/

    -rw-r--r-- /home/mediawikiDBpsw/DBpsw.php
```

and included **/home/mediawikiDBpsw/DBpsw.php** to the **/server/web/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php**

But as you can see, the folders **/server/web/mediawiki**, **/home/mediawikiDBpsw/** and the files **/home/mediawikiDBpsw/DBpsw.php** , **/server/web/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php** are accessible to others (readable). Thus anyone "other" who has access to the server can ssh to the folder **/server/web/mediawiki** read the file **LocalSettings.php**, learn the path **/home/mediawikiDBpsw/DBpsw.php** from there and read the DataBase settings (user/password) from **/home/mediawikiDBpsw/DBpsw.php**.

**Question 2**: How can I protect DataBase settings (user/password) from the "other" users that have access to the server?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you do this step: “Check with your distro for what the webserver's user is (this varies, examples include "apache", "nobody","httpd"). Then set the permissions for the password file like so […]”?

Comment: Gumbo, thank you! Changing group to web server user solved the problem. Now others can't read the file, but mediawiki works as server user can read it.

Comment: Related: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Chmod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group of the file **/home/mediawikiDBpsw/DBpsw.php** with DataBase settings should be changed to the webserver's user group (use chgrp).

Than rights of the file should be changed to (use chmod)

```
w-rw-r----- /home/mediawikiDBpsw/DBpsw.php
```

Now, mediawiki will run, because webserver's user will have access to the DataBase settings. Still DataBase settings will be safe as others will not have reading access to **/home/mediawikiDBpsw/DBpsw.php** (unless they are in the same group as webserver's user, which shouldn't be the case).

Comment: Protecting only database config file is not enough.  Some malicious user might alter application source code and make webserver to dump password to another file.  Make sure that all files are write-protected for unwanted users.  Also, it's good to run every application as different user.  Otherwise the other applications could be used to break into your MediaWiki site.

Comment: @skalee. I checked the directory with mediawiki for writable files by group and others with **find . -perm /o+w,g+w** and didn't find any. I read in [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/17364/how-do-i-find-all-files-and-directories-writable-by-a-specific-user) that it is better to do **sudo -u nobody find . -writable**, but I don't have access to the **sudo** command on the server. I appreciate your suggestion about creating additional user to be owner of mediawiki directory with his own password, but I can't do it, because I don't have rights to create user.